# Failed to Start up Zeppelin

Tags: apache-zeppelin

I just downloaded zeppelin-0.8.2 binary package and unzipped it. I am on **Windows 10**.

I have set up `JAVA_HOME` and `SPARK_HOME` correctly. I want to start it up locally.

When I run `zeppelin-0.8.2-bin-all> bin\zeppelin.cmd` as per the instruction from Apache Zeppelin site, it gave me error:

```
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=512m; support was removed in 8.0
Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.zeppelin.server.ZeppelinServer
```

I checked and found `zeppelin-server-0.8.2.jar` under `\zeppelin-0.8.2-bin-all\lib` folder, but it still giving me that error. Do I need to compile again locally???

Can someone please advise? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem.
It was due to incorrect environment variable %ZEPPELIN_HOME%. I previously installed 0.9.0 version and removed it subsequently, but I forgot to change it to 0.8.2 after I reinstalled the 0.8.2 version.